# meta tag for compatibility mode

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have web app with lots of JS and jQuery code and my problem is with IE9. For some reason my JS is not responding in IE9, in all other browsers is working well including IE8.

What is happening is that when I put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>` the JS is working in IE9 but not like in other browsers (some of the features are not working well), then when I change it to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>` and refresh everything starts to work fine, but if I clear the cache and restart browser I have the same problem again.

I've also tried to remove meta tag totally but that doesn't help. If someone have more experience with IE any advice is welcome.

> Note: This problem is appears only on online server, locally on my WAMP is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a link to your page?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What features don't work well in what browsers? As far as I can tell, your `meta` tag is doing exactly what it ought to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because page is protected and I can't provide user and pass. In all other browsers is working great just IE9 is making problem. The only way how it work but not permanent is:
"What is happening is that when I put <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/> the JS is working in IE9 but not like in other browsers, then when I change it to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/> and refresh everything starts to work fine, but if I clear the cache and restart browser I have the same problem again."

Comment: Well, yeah -- that's what `content="IE=8"` is *supposed* to do -- force the browser into IE8 mode. If you want IE9 to use IE9 browser mode, either change it to `content="IE=edge"` or remove the `meta` tag entirely.